# A query that counts the number of records from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables `merchants`:

```
merchant_id |  merchant_name  | ... |
-------------------------------------
      1     | merchant name 1 | ... |
      2     | merchant name 2 | ... |
      3     | merchant name 3 | ... |
```

Product Table `products`:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... |
------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |
```

And there are table `likes_products`:

```
 like_id |  product_Id  | user_id |
-----------------------------------
    1    |      101     |   101   |
    2    |      102     |   102   |
    3    |      103     |   101   |
```

Table `likes_merchants`:

```
 like_id |  merchants_Id  | user_id |
-----------------------------------
    1    |       107      |   101   |
    2    |       108      |   102   |
    3    |       109      |   101   |
```

Table `bookmarks_products`:

```
 bookmark_id |  product_Id  | user_id |
---------------------------------------
       1     |      101     |   101   |
       2     |      102     |   102   |
       3     |      103     |   101   |
```

I make a request that displays all the products, counts their number of likes. Then he looks like the user from the user who is now authorized products, and if this user has the product tabs, and displays `true` or `false`:

```
SELECT P.* , 
  COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS LIKES,
  (B.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) AS BOOKMARKS,
  (L.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) AS IS_LIKED
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
      LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON (B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
      LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON (L.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
        GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID, B.PRODUCT_ID, L.PRODUCT_ID
          ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID
```

My problem is that there:
1) I can’t check what an authorized user likes or likes in bookmarks. If any caller likes a product or bookmarks it, he will release `true`.

2) I can not understand why he considers the number of likes and bookmarks together. That is: if a user has put a like and bookmarked a product, then one like is put, then another user has bookmarked this product, then the likes have increased, and if he likes this product, they will be doubled.

Help me understand my problem please

What I expect to receive:

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | LIKES | BOOKMARKS | IS_LIKED |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   1   |   false   |   true   |
      2     | product name 2 | ... |   0   |   true    |   true   |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   5   |   false   |   false  |
```

But the problem is that if there are likes from users in the `table, there are bookmarks from users in the` table, it sums them up and outputs the correct half-half likes.

This is what happens without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT P.* , 
  (B.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) AS BOOKMARKS,
  (L.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL) AS IS_LIKED
    FROM PRODUCTS AS P
      LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON (B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
      LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON (L.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID)
          ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_ID
```

```
 product_id |  product_name  | ... | LIKES | BOOKMARKS | IS_LIKED |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   1   |   false   |   true   |
      1     | product name 1 | ... |   1   |   false   |   true   |
      3     | product name 3 | ... |   5   |   false   |   false  |
```

Product 1 is entered twice as it is in two tables `likes_products` and `bookmarks_products`

Comment: could you please add your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 I added that I want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select A.product_id,likes,
case when B.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL then 'true' else 'false' end AS BOOKMARKS,
case when L.PRODUCT_ID IS NOT NULL then 'true' else 'false' end AS IS_LIKED
from
(  
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID , 
  COUNT(L.USER_ID) AS LIKES,
  FROM PRODUCTS AS P
  LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON L.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
  GROUP BY P.PRODUCT_ID
)A 
LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON B.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
LEFT JOIN LIKES_PRODUCTS AS L ON L.PRODUCT_ID = A.PRODUCT_ID
order by A.product_id
```

Comment: He writes a mistake: `missing FROM-clause entry for table "p" ` on line `LEFT JOIN BOOKMARKS_PRODUCTS AS B ON B.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID`
                                                    ^`

Comment: @MegaRoks, you can check now

Comment: Yes, the query is working. But he displays twice the product 1